# The type or namespace name 'Employee' could not be found in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am working with Entity Framework database first approach. I have selected the table which I created in database to my model while creation. But unfortunately it is throwing an exception like as follows in `Model1.context.cs` file:

> The type or namespace name 'Employee' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ConsoleApp6 C:\Users\lenovo\source\repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Models\Model1.Context.cs

I am having only one `Employee` table in my database. And that was created in `edmx` UML diagram also but not able to see the class which it should get generated. What could be the problem?

Error throws at :

```
public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

As like `Employee` class not exist.

Comment: This post may be useful: [Table missing from 'EF Designer from database' .edmx diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660765/table-missing-from-ef-designer-from-database-edmx-diagram).

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin The link you suggested is issue due to constraints  with multiple tables. I am having only one table with primary key.

Comment: You are right, I missed the point that there is a single table in the DB.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin Yes, Not understanding what could be the problem. Not able to generate class for my table.